# How to clear the previous fragment check boxes while passing into next fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had a sliding tabs fragment activity having of 4 fragments and in each fragments i had a check boxes.Here i need to uncheck the previous fragment check box when i was entered into the next fragment is it possible can any one tell me how to do this please help me.I Google it,But i didn't found any answer please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

override the onResume() of your activity which holds the fragments to:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

then in your fragments add this method

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    yourCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    super.onResume();
}
```